# New Area 51 Site Layout

Tags: discussion, area-51

I was just on Area 51 to find out they have changed the site's layout, and I find it a bit confusing. Like comments: it is not possible to post comments on the topic instead of the question.

I have found this from my Sports one but can someone please explain why this has happened?

I guess this must have happened in the last 12 hours because that's the last time I was on it.

Comment: I think it was more like 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Actually, I think it just happened. There was just a [notice in the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/478947#478947) naught but a few minutes ago.

Comment: @mmyers do you know why this has happend

Comment: Nifty... Although, I'm not sure why "Life" has so few proposals in comparison to "All Proposals"... Or why there's no "Death" category...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the new Area 51!  There will be a blog post to explain everything soon, but to answer your question in the meantime, comments have been replaced with discussions, which are full questions & answers on the new [discuss.area51.stackexchange.com](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com).

You can still view old comments, but from now on you should create a discussion instead.  There's a link on the proposal page to quickly create a new question with the appropriate tag and a link to the proposal pre-filled for you.

Comment: can the discussions still be about the proposal?

Comment: @Benny Yes, the intent of discuss.area51.stackexchange.com is to provide *more* discussion / commenting ability.  Instead of a single thread of comments, you can have many discussions about a proposal, or discussions about multiple proposals.

Comment: Does that mean I can talk about it there and it can't be closed?

Comment: @Benny Yes, discuss.area51.stackexchange.com is where you discuss anything to do with proposals: "Should X be closed?", "Should X be merged with Y?", "Should X include subject Z?" etc